# cant call jquery function with onclick event

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

i wrote this code, to change the previous textbox value  but its not working  , by clicking on ok button i want to change Text1 text.its only a example to show the problem , i cant not access to ID of that Textbox! so in code i go until visit the div with class=stop and change the textbox value

```
<div style="width:500px;" class="siblings">
    <div class="stop" > </div>
    <input  id="Text1" type="text" /> <br>
    <--!  more elements will be  here  !-->
    <input  type="Button" value="ok" onclick='$(this).parent().prevUntil("div.stop").val("new text");'/>                                                                    
</div>
```

Comment: What you are describing in the text is different from I see in the code. What I understand from your text is: When I clic the button I want to change Text1 input text. What I understand from your code is: When I press the button I want to change div with class stop text to something else. Could you please confirm what is expected to do.

Comment: When you click the button I want to change Text1 input text! but the problem is i in my problem i dont have the ID of Textbox.you know its only a example to show the problem , i cant not access to ID of that Textbox! so in code i go until visit the div with class=stop and change the textbox value !

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The way to call the jQuery function like that would be to put it in a javascript function like so:

### HTML

```
<input  type="Button" value="ok" onclick='myFunction(this)'/>
```

### Javascript/Jquery

```
function myFunction(that){
    $(this).parent().find('input[type="text"]:first-child').val('new text');
}
```

The way most people use jQuery and click events are without anything being called from the HTML itself. It would look like this:

### Pure jQuery

```
$('input[type="button"]').click(function(){
    $(this).parent().find('input[type="text"]:first-child').val('new text');
});
```

Accessing `<input id="Text1" type="text"/>` -

This is the tree traversal you should be able to use, if the `#Text1` is the first input element :

```
$(this).parent().find('input[type="text"]:first-child').val('new text');
```

Comment: @MohammadOlfatMiri although I did change it to find, as I think that is a better choice than children

Comment: may you visited this http://jsfiddle.net/FZk66/6/. its my real problem. your code solved my example problem not my real problem. as i said this example is only for showing my problem

Comment: @MohammadOlfatMiri - I'm not Adjit, but for the fiddle you linked to, if you update `parent` to `closest` (and pass the class selector 'panel') and then change `children` to `find` (children is one level only), it will work. Here's an updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/FZk66/7/

Comment: @MohammadOlfatMiri yeah, you just have to change your tree traversal. That is the biggest part of this.

Answer (score 2):

Let's take a look at your script and break it down.

```
$(this).parent().prevUntil("div.stop").val("new text");
```

`$(this)` - selects the `button`.

`BUTTON.parent()` - has now selected `<div style="width:500px;" class="siblings">`

`DIV.prevUntil("div.stop")` - Here, you're saying "from our SELECTED div, get all PREVIOUS SIBLINGS UNTIL we we see a `DIV` that has a class of `stop`.

So, if your DOM tree looked like this:

```
DIV.nope
DIV.stop
DIV.go
DIV.siblings
    DIV.stop
    INPUT
    BUTTON
```

clicking the BUTTON would select `.siblings` and then select all the DIVs with `.go` classes in our mark up (but not `.stop` or `.nope`) Again, this is because `.prevUntil` will only select all siblings for `.siblings` until the selector matches.

At this point, IF you had an element(s), you would be attempting to set the `value` attribute to "new text" (but since our selected element is a DIV, this is probably not what you want...)

What you actually want to do is something like this:

When a user clicks the `button`, go up to a common `parent` of the `button` and `input` and then select the input and change the `value`.

```
$(this).parent().find('input[type=text]').val('new text')
```

.parent() selects the common parent, `.find()` selects the input, and then `val` updates the value.

But, what if you have multiple inputs, and would like to use `div.stop` as a pivot for your input? (You know, for instance, `div.stop` will always proceed your input? You could do something like this:

```
$(this).parent().find('div.stop + input').val('new text');
```

Here's a fiddle to demonstrate: http://jsfiddle.net/7Najs/

Answer (score 0):

I don't see why where's a need for the "stop" element if you can directly access the input val by the ID. Because of that I would do the following:

```
<div style="width:500px;" class="siblings">
    <input id="Text1" type="text" /> <br>
    <!--  more elements will be  here  -->
    <input type="Button" value="ok" onclick="$('#Text1').val('new text');" />
</div>
```

Also the HTML comments were a bit off, updated that as well.

Comment: its only a example to show the problem , i cant not access to ID of that Textbox! so in code i go until visit the div with class=stop and change the textbox value

Answer (score 0):

I don't quite understand the reason you say you can't access the textbox id. Here is a quick example on how you modify the Text input with 4 buttons, each with a different value.

```
 <div style="width:500px;" class="siblings">
    <input id="Text1" type="text" /> <br>
     <!--  more elements will be  here  -->
   <input type="Button" value="ok" onclick="$('#Text1').val('new text');" />
   <input type="Button" value="ok" onclick="$('#Text1').val('other text');" />
   <input type="Button" value="ok" onclick="$('#Text1').val('another text');" />
   <input type="Button" value="ok" onclick="$('#Text1').val('next text');" />
</div>
```

Here is a JSBin:  http://jsbin.com/zufesici/1/edit